# Vb Net check if arrayList contains a substring

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I am using `myArrayList.Contains(myString)` and `myArrayList.IndexOf(myString)` to check if arrayList contains provided string and get its index respectively.

But, How could I check if contains a substring?

```
Dim myArrayList as New ArrayList()
myArrayList.add("sub1;sub2")
myArrayList.add("sub3;sub4")
```

so, something like, `myArrayList.Contains("sub3")` should return True

Comment: Any reason you are using an old ArrayList rather than a `List(of String)`?

Comment: yes, because I am currently using some old functions that return an ArrayList. However, no problem to turn into List. Then, same question for Lists. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could use the ArrayList to search for substrings with

```
Dim result = myArrayList.ToArray().Any(Function(x) x.ToString().Contains("sub3"))
```

Of course the advice to use a strongly typed List(Of String) is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your question goes, without discussing why do you need ArrayList, because array list is there only for backwards compatibility - to select indexes of items that contain specific string, the best performance you will get here

```
Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)(100)

For i As Integer = 0 to myArrayList.Count - 1
    If DirectCast(myArrayList(i), String).Contains("sub3") Then
        indexes.Add(i)
    End If
Next
```

Again, this is if you need to get your indexes. In your case, `ArrayList.Contains` - you testing whole object [string in your case]. While you need to get the string and test it's part using `String.Contains`

If you want to test in non case-sensitive manner, you can use `String.IndexOf`